# Column that describes which items from a list this entity has

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a mysql database and I have a table `user` that has a field called `achievements` in which I want to set what achievements this user unlocked.

It would something like an array with `size = number of achievements` and `'true'` in the positions in which the user has this achievement. I guess is not possible to do it this way in mysql, so what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will use this column only for display in an application (eg a web page), you can store the data as a string, and then convert it to the desired display, or even convert direct to an array (in PHP for instance):

```
CREATE TABLE users (userid INT, username VARCHAR(100), achievements VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO users (userid, username, achievements) VALUES 
(1, 'Mary', 'c1=>true,c2=>false,c3=>false,c4=>true'), 
(2, 'Sophia', 'c1=>false,c2=>true,c3=>true,c4=>true'),
(3, 'Margot', 'c1=>true,c2=>false,c3=>false,c4=>true');
```

However, if you intend to use this data as information in your relational data model (for example, search for all records that have the option c1 = true and c3 = false, or count all the records that have c3 = true...), the best alternative is to work with a derived table, and work with numbers instead strings:

```
CREATE TABLE users (userid INT, username VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE options (userid INT, achievementkey CHAR(2), achievementval TINYINT);

INSERT INTO users (userid, username) VALUES 
(1, 'Mary'), 
(2, 'Sophia'),
(3, 'Margot');

INSERT INTO options (userid, achievementkey, achievementval) VALUES 
(1, 'c1', 1), 
(1, 'c2', 0), 
(1, 'c3', 1), 
(2, 'c1', 1), 
(2, 'c2', 0), 
(2, 'c3', 1), 
(3, 'c1', 0), 
(3, 'c2', 0), 
(3, 'c3', 1);
```

That way you have an ideal model for queries of achievementS for all users, or to make AGGREGATIONS (sum, count, average, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use 3 tables for this, 1 of them being a join table:

```
+--------+    +---------------+    +------------------+
| User   |    | Achievement   |    | User_Achievement |
+--------+    +---------------+    +------------------+
| UserID |    | AchievementID |    | UserID           |
+--------+    +---------------+    | AchievementID    |
                                   +------------------+
```

`User` stores all of your users, `Achievement` stores the master list of all possible achievements, and `User_Achievement` *joins* them together.  So, for example you might have:

```
+----------------+    +-------------------------------+
| User           |    | Achievement                   |
+--------+-------+    +---------------+---------------+
| UserID | Name  |    | AchievementID | Name          |
+--------+-------+    +---------------+---------------+
|      1 | Alice |    |             1 | Flag Capturer |
|      2 | Bob   |    |             2 | Headshot      |
|      3 | Carol |    |             3 | Fastest Time  |
+--------+-------+    +---------------+---------------+

       +------------------------+
       | User_Achievement       |
       +--------+---------------+
       | UserID | AchievementID |
       +--------+---------------+
       |      1 |             1 |
       |      1 |             3 |
       |      2 |             1 |
       |      2 |             2 |
       |      2 |             3 |
       +--------+---------------+
```

So in this case, Alice has two achievements, Bob has 3, and Carol has 0.